# Azure ToolKit for Eclipse install issue

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I am following the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/eclipse/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation to install Azure toolkit for eclipse. But when I choose http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/ I do not see the option Azure Toolkit for Java. I am using Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers(Oxygen) and am on Windows 7.

I also tried installing from Eclipse market place and I get error "The following solutions are not available Azure Toolkit for Eclipse 3.5.0"

Comment: Based on the information in Eclipse marketplace -  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/azure-toolkit-eclipse, Oxygen is supported. I don't have an Oxygen version handy, but I have this installed successfully on my Mars version. Is there any other info provided by the error message besides just the "The following solutions are not available..." text.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/eclipse/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation) and installed the Azure Toolkit successfully. Please refer to my situation.

My eclipse version:

[image]

Solution A: Click the Help menu, and then click Install New Software

[image]

Solution B: Install from Eclipse market place

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: In the Install New Software window, I only see Team Explorer Everywhere but not the Azure Toolkit option. I do not see any other errors in the log. Do we need any subscription or is there a chance some firewall is blocking the Azure toolkit?

Comment: @teema teema,I don't know the actual situation on your side. Per my knowledge, no need for any subscription or any firewall restriction.Could you re-install the IDE to try again or try with lower version IDE? In addition , could you please post the screenshot of the exception when you install tool in market place? Thx.

Comment: I have the same issue. I only see the Team Explorere everywhere but not the Azure Toolkit option. Was there already any sollution for this?
When I try to install the plugin using the marketplace the repository cannot be read. I think is a problem on Microsoft side.